# How to Check if an External ID is Present in a (BIM) Model Stored on Autodesk Forge Servers (SVF2/SVF)?

Tags: metadata, revit-api, autodesk-model-derivative

I am building a BIM verification tool and need to confirm whether a specific external ID (GUID) is present in BIM models stored on Autodesk Forge. I have successfully done this for locally-stored models by examining the objects_ids.json.gz file from the SVF structure.

However, for models stored on Autodesk's Forge servers, I'm looking for an efficient and less complex way to achieve the same task. I am aware of the Metadata API, but it seems too complex for what I need, as it includes all textual properties in the model.

My question is: Is there a streamlined way to check only for the presence of a specific external ID in a BIM model stored on Autodesk Forge?

Thank you for your guidance!

Answer (score 0):

For Revit model, it's actually the [Element.UniqueId](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2024/f9a9cb77-6913-6d41-ecf5-4398a24e8ff8.htm) in Revit API.

You can use [POST {urn}/metadata/{modelGuid}/properties:query](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/metadata/urn-metadata-guid-properties-query-POST/) of Model Derivative API to query by external id to check if the object of this external id is in the model.

```bash
curl -X 'POST' \
     -H 'Authorization: Bearer PtnrvrtSRpWwUi3407QhgvqdUVKL...'  \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -V 'https://developer-dev.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6bW9kZWxfZGVyaXZhdGl2ZV9wcm9wX2VuaGFuY2VtZW50X3Rlc3RpbmcvcmFjX2Jhc2ljX3NhbXBsZV9wcm9qZWN0LnJ2dA/metadata/6bfb4886-f2ee-9ccb-8db0-c5c170220c40/properties:query' \
     -D '{
              "query": {
                  "$in": [
                      "externalId",
                      "e3e052f9-0156-11d5-9301-0000863f27ad-00000153",
                      "5e8712a2-e372-44b6-9e73-0aaa430558ee-0008656f"
                  ]
              },
              "fields": [
                  "name",
                  "externalId"
              ],
              "pagination": {
                  "offset": 0,
                  "limit": 20
              },
              "payload": "text"
          }'
```